# How to change the active color for the Navbar on a single page application [Bootstrap]

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying making concept profile page and so far I have been stuck trying to change to active background color of the navbar to something other than the default white.

I've tried using  ".nav li:active" but that only changes the color when I click on the button and then it goes to white again. "body .nav>.active>a " Also does nothing so at this point I'm at a loss as to how I'm suppose to customise it.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #1A85C9;
  padding: 20px;
  border-style: none;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-right: 300px;
}
.navbar a {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
  color: white !important;
}
.nav li:active {
  background-color: #D65108 !important;
}
.nav li {
  margin-left: 10px
}
body .nav>.active>a {
  background-color: #EFA00B
}
.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #003EBA;
  border-radius: 10px
}
#about {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ED3500
}
#portfolio {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #F09F00
}
#contact {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #8AD13B
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <b>Concept Portfolio SPA </b>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#about"><b>ABOUT</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio"><b>PORTFOLIO</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact"><b>CONTACT ME</b></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="about"></div>
  <div id="portfolio"></div>
  <div id="contact"></div>

</body>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess the best is to use jquery to add the *active* on click...

Answer (score 0):

So I've worked out that the active color is changed with

```html
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: ######;
}
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to anyone else that comes across this post with the same problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for future (in case you find it helpful):

If you want to change property of any element then just right click on that element and click on 'inspect element' (or do a PF12 in chrome). You'll then see the elements or the classes applied and then you can easily decide what and where the change needs to be made.

.

Answer (score -1):

```css
   

 .navbar {
      background-color: #1A85C9;
      padding: 20px;
      border-style: none;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
      color: white;
      padding-left: 300px;
      padding-right: 300px;
    }
    .navbar a {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
      color: white !important;
    }
    .nav li:active {
      background-color: #D65108 !important;
    }
    .nav li {
      margin-left: 10px
    }
    body .nav>.active>a {
      background-color: #EFA00B
!important;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .nav li:hover {
      background-color: #003EBA;
      border-radius: 10px
    }
    #about {
      padding: 40px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #ED3500
    }
    #portfolio {
      padding: 40px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #F09F00
    }
    #contact {
      padding: 40px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #8AD13B
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <b>Concept Portfolio SPA </b>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#about"><b>ABOUT</b></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio"><b>PORTFOLIO</b></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><b>CONTACT ME</b></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div id="about"></div>
      <div id="portfolio"></div>
      <div id="contact"></div>

    </body>
```